# redirect my client PC to default login page

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have a server and 5 PCs connected to it. I want to archive implement the following,

Whenever any of the PCs tries to access internet(tries to browse Google o u-tube o what so ever), I want to redirect the PC to a login page. Login page will contain username and password. Unless and until they enter the username and password correctly, they wont be allowed to browse internet.

> How to block the PCs??

I am a newb in network programming. I have no idea how to archive this.

Is this possible to do this in java o any other platform??
If so then please guide me...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: your a "newb to network programming" and you have a server with 5 pcs connected to it? Are you sure? - edit: its called a router, and a wifi password

Comment: This is a standard procedure for most hotels, libraries, and other places that offer some form of wifi.  When you open your browser and access the wireless access point, the first page is some kind of login page often with disclaimers and policies of use.  It is called a captive portal.  See this stackoverflow http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14561/is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-login-page-for-your-own-wi-fi-hotspot and maybe start with Chillispot open source http://www.chillispot.org/

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are seeking for something like they have it on public wifi (hotels,library etc) [Bluesocket](http://www.adtran.com/) and [chillispot](http://www.chillispot.org/).if you want to program the same guess you can have a look at chillspot [sourcecode](http://www.chillispot.org/download/chillispot-1.1.0.tar.gz)

i think then you should do it on your Router itself.

[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com)

on windows You can setup VPN.

[How to Set Up a Virtual Private Network with Windows](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-a-Virtual-Private-Network-with-Windows)

[How to Create a VPN Server on Your Windows Computer Without Installing Any Software](http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/)

[How to setup a VPN Server in Windows Server 2008](http://jesin.tk/how-to-setup-a-vpn-server-in-windows-server-2008/)

Comment: yes chillispot is mainly for linux right?? I need some software soucrecode to run on windows server

Comment: I want something for hotspots and vpn is for lan connections right?? and also i will have to choose the users accessing my net. Actually i want to redirect them directly unless they have the pass key